# Get data from server side using vis.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets, vis.js

I have a set of relatives of a community stored in a database with the relations between theirselves.

I'm try to based on a person, get all the decedents of this one and represent in a network graph using vis.js.

All the request are made using ajax so i need a way to get the nodes and the edges from a servlet. I've check the documentation and it seems the only way is creating a json file where it is stored in a local path and then load it, but to me it is very archaic due to the site it's going to be used by dozens of people.

Here is the code:

```
var network = null;
var layoutMethod = "directed";

function destroy() {
  if (network !== null) {
    network.destroy();
    network = null;
  }
}

function draw() {
  destroy();

    // randomly create some nodes and edges\n" +
var nodes = <%= request.getParameter("nodes") %>;
var edges = <%= request.getParameter("edges") %>;

  // create a network\n" +

var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
};
// create a network
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
var options = {

};
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
}
```

So everytime you choose a person, the action is triggered and the network must be updated:

```
 $('#subscribe').click(function()    
 {
     $('#descripcion').find('span').remove().end();
     $('#descripcion').find('br').remove().end();


     $.get( "Almacen", { valor: "C",email:$('#email').val()},function( data){
    $("#descripcion").append(data);

}
              );
    draw();

 });
```

Any idea of a way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be conflating the topic of grabbing data for the network, with that of updating the network. When you grab your data via ajax, you should save it in some javascript data structure, and then update your vis.js network based on this data. To update the vis.js network, you can use the 'update' method on the 'nodes' and 'edges' visDataSets.
That is,

nodes.update([node1, node2, node3]);

or

edges.update([edge1, edge2, edge3]);

where node 'i' and edge 'i' are objects describing your updates (or additions) to the nodes/edges, and they always include an 'id' field, so that vis.js understands which node/edge in the graph to add/update.

Example:
nodes.update([{id: 324, title: "My node's new title"}, {id: 456, hidden: true}]);
this example modifies a node 324's title and hides node 456 (if the nodes did not exist in the network yet, then it would actually create them).